# Excel - Lookup if name exists in different worksheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-365

so i have an Excel File with two worksheets. One of them has some servernames and all the different data in there. the other one also has the servernames, but with an ending (like ".domain.net") Also these are listed more than once in the sheet, depending what runs on them.

Is there a funktion that can outputhow many times the server from worksheet one is listed in worksheet two?

Note: The servers in worksheet one range from A4 to A3800.
The servers in worksheet two range from A2 to A7113.
It could also happen, that the server from WS 1 does not appear in WS 2.

Thanks for helping out.

Kind regards
Elias

Comment: Use COUNTIF with wildcards

Comment: it can be simple as this `=COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,A5 &"."&"*")`

Comment: Thanks @NoobVB, it workes absolutly flawless.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Something like this should work:

```
=COUNTIF($G$2:$G$5;"*"&A2&"*")
```